# msmtp-mta: Add $HOSTNAME to every mail

Tags: sendmail, mailx

I have a fleet of Ubuntu clients running `msmtp-mta` along with `heirloom-mailx`.
I'd like to have the same `/etc/msmtprc` on all machines.

At present, when someone uses `mailx` or `sendmail`, the mail will be from `user@mydomain.com` and the only clue to the client machine is the IP address in the mail header.

Is there a way to add the client host name to every mail sent? Like

- Prepend it to the subject or
- auto-attach a file to any mail or
- change `mydomain.com` to `client.mydomain.com` (remember, one file to rule them all, and changes in host name should be met automatically)

**Note:** I cannot configure the actual SMTP-Server, just the `msmtp` client.

Comment: You could try ssmtp instead of msmtp. I use msmtp myself, but you have to set the maildomain in the msmtprc for that; ssmtp uses the hostname directly I think. If you can settle for "the same msmtprc except for the maildomain", then `client.mydomain.com` should be possible with msmtp.

Comment: Nice one, frostschutz! I would upvote you if I could! Note: I installed both `(m|s)smtp`, let `msmtp` provide `sendmail` so users can use `mailx` as they are used to. `root` and other reporting system accounts get a `.mailrc` that uses `ssmtp` as `sendmail` and hence provide the one-to-rule-them-all host name config `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been answered in the comments:

> You could try ssmtp instead of msmtp. I use msmtp myself, but you have to set the maildomain in the msmtprc for that; ssmtp uses the hostname directly I think. If you can settle for "the same msmtprc except for the maildomain", then client.mydomain.com should be possible with msmtp. – [frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz)

followed by:

> Note: I installed both (m|s)smtp, let msmtp provide sendmail so users can use mailx as they are used to. root and other reporting system accounts get a .mailrc that uses ssmtp as sendmail and hence provide the one-to-rule-them-all host name config /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf. – [arney](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/36762/arney)